# Proof that there are infinitely many prime numbers starting with a given digit string

Tags: prime-numbers

To prove the following fact: given any sequence of digits in any base, eg 314159265358979323 base 10, there are infinitely many primes that start with these digits,eg when expressed in decimal they start with 314159265358979323. I think using a prime number theorem will be helpful . But I am still not getting a point of how to start the proof.

Comment: Note that "$n$ starts with $314159265358979323$" is equivalent to "there exists $k \in \mathbb N$ such that $314159265358979323 \cdot 10^k \le n < 314159265358979324 \cdot 10^k$".  Can you show that the union of these intervals for all $k$ must contain infinitely many primes?

Comment: I am a little suspicious that two people asked the same question less than an hour apart. Can you give the source of the question?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2440482

Answer (score 23):

We use the Prime Number Theorem, nothing else, and do all the details for a particular case.  The method used can be easily transferred to the general case.

Let $\pi(x)$ be the number of primes that are less than or equal to $x$.
 For any real number $x>1$, let $F(x)=\dfrac{x}{\ln x}$. The Prime Number Theorem says that
 $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\pi(x)}{F(x)}=1.$$
 By the *definition* of limit, given any positive $\epsilon$, we have
 $$1-\epsilon <\frac{\pi(x)}{F(x)} <1+\epsilon\qquad\text{(Inequality $1$)}$$
 if $x$ is large enough.  (The meaning of "large enough" depends on the value of $\epsilon$.)

We will show that there are infinitely many primes whose hexadecimal representation starts with $324$.  Why $324$? The *hexadecimal* representation of $\pi$ starts with $3.24$. The OP used a much longer string of digits, also connected to $\pi$. But something of that length, in either hex or decimal, would be a nuisance to type. It seems appropriate to use initial "digits" of $\pi$, since we will be working with $\pi(x)$.  Why hexadecimal? To show that the base does not matter.  Also, the question originally came from a programming site!  Why not use a general beginning and a general base?  Because doing so might conceal the basic simplicity of the argument.

**Important Note**: In what follows, the numbers $324$ and $325$ appear often.  They are **always** to be read as numbers to the base $16$. (So, for example, $324$ refers to the number which in base ten would be written as $804$.)  The base $16$ occurs fairly often. Of course, it must be read in base ten! The few other numbers that appear, unless it is otherwise specified, are to be read as base $16$ numbers.  Occasionally, for emphasis, the base is explicitly mentioned.

We want to show that there are arbitrarily large integers $n$ for which there is a prime $p$ with
$$324_{16}\times 16^n <p < 325_{16}\times 16^n.$$
(The above inequality is equivalent to saying that the first three hexadecimal "digits" of $p$ are $3$, $2$, and $4$.)

By Inequality $1$, the number of
  primes  less than $325\times 16^n$ is $>(1-\epsilon)F(325\times 16^n)$.  Again by Inequality $1$, the number of primes less than $324\times 16^n$ is $<(1+\epsilon)F(324\times 16^n)$.  So the number of primes in the interval 
($324_{16}\times 16^n, 325_{16}\times 16^n)$ is greater than $(1-\epsilon)F(325\times 16^n) -(1+\epsilon)F(324\times 16^n)$.
Thus if
$$(1-\epsilon)F(325\times 16^n) -(1+\epsilon)F(324\times 16^n)>0,$$
there must be at least one prime between our two bounds. (Recall that we are *counting* primes. If an inequality tells us the count is greater than $0$, that count is at least $1$.)

So we want to choose $n$ large enough so that Inequality $1$ is satisfied, and such that 
$$(1-\epsilon)\frac{325\times 16^n}{\ln(325\times 16^n)}>(1+\epsilon)\frac{324\times 16^n}{\ln(324\times 16^n)}.$$
The "laws of logarithms," together with some rearranging, show that the above inequality is equivalent to
$$n(\ln 16)(1-649\epsilon)>(1+\epsilon)(324)(\ln 325)-(1-\epsilon)(325)(\ln 324)\qquad\text{(Inequality $2$)}$$
Note that $649$ is to be read in base $16$. Now we are ready for the final push.

First, let  $\epsilon$ be the reciprocal of $1000_{16}$ (this reciprocal is safely less than the reciprocal of $649_{16}$).

Then on the left of Inequality $2$ we have $n$ times a positive constant, and on the right we have a constant.  Next, let $n$ be large enough to ensure that Inequality $1$ is satisfied for our chosen value of $\epsilon$ and $x >324\times 16^n$.

Finally, let $n$ be also large enough to ensure that Inequality $2$ is satisfied for our chosen value of $\epsilon$. Then there is always a prime between $324_{16}\times 16^n$ and $325_{16}\times 16^n$, that is, a prime whose initial hexadecimal "digits" are $3$, $2$, and $4$.

Only minor editing changes are needed to make the argument work for any initial "digit" sequence, and any base.

Comment: +1 Very nice. A small nitpick. $315$ and $314$ are hex-digits, so $629$ is also in base-16. So, that particular choice of $\epsilon$ may not work... (Unless, of course, you meant $1000$ in base-16 as well :-))

Comment: @Srivatsan Narayanan: Thanks for pointing out the ambiguities. I have edited to make it (I hope) very clear which numbers are to be read in base $16$ and which are not.  And yes, $1000$ is to be read in base $16$!

Answer (score 16):

A [simple consequence of the PNT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate#Better_results) is the fact that for any real number $k>1$ there exists an $n_0$ such that there is a prime between $n$ and $kn$ for all $n > n_0$.  Now suppose your desired starting base-$b$ sequence is $d$ digits long; set $k = 1 + b^{-d}$ and apply the preceding fact.

Comment: +1 Sweet. A small nitpick. Since the question asks about a general base $b$ (not necessarily $10$) perhaps you can modify the $k$ to $1+b^{-d}$ to make the answer more accurate.

Answer (score 6):

This is a special case of the following fact, a simple and short proof of which appears on p. 4 of [Disjunctive sequences: An overview](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.34.1370), by Calude, Priese and Staiger (1997):

- If $a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots$ , is a strictly
  increasing infinite sequence of positive integers such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (a_{n+1}/a_{n}) = 1$, then for any
  positive integer $m$ and any integer base $b ≥ 2$, there is some (and hence infinitely many) 
  $a_n$ whose expression in base $b$ starts with the expression
  of $m$ in base $b$.

The desired result follows by taking $a_n$ to be the $n$th prime $p_n$, noting that the [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) implies $p_n \sim n \ln n$, and hence that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (p_{n+1}/p_{n}) = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the prime number theorem to prove that there is an N such that for every M>N there is at least one prime that is written as 314159265358979323 followed by M other digits.

(Heuristically: There are $10^M$ possible numbers of this form, and the probability of each of them being prime is asymptotically proportional to 1/M -- thus the *expected* number of primes in each such interval grows towards infinity. Devising a rigorous argument from this sketch and one of the exact-bound versions of the prime number theorem is left as an exercise :-)