# Is every natural number a prefix of a prime number?

Tags: prime-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof that there are infinitely many prime numbers starting with a given digit string](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60825/proof-that-there-are-infinitely-many-prime-numbers-starting-with-a-given-digit-s)

Let n be the representation of a natural number in a non-unary base. Is it a prefix of the representation of a prime number over the same base?

For example: in decimal, the answer for 10 is yes, because 103 is prime.
Is this true for every number?

EDIT: As Henning Makholm has pointed out, this question has been asked before:
[Proof that there are infinitely many prime numbers starting with a given digit string](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60825/proof-that-there-are-infinitely-many-prime-numbers-starting-with-a-given-digit-s)

Comment: Not only is there always such a prime -- there are infinitely many, as demonstrated in the question [Proof that there are infinitely many prime numbers starting with a given digit string](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60825/proof-that-there-are-infinitely-many-prime-numbers-starting-with-a-given-digit-s)

Comment: I think your question is more complicated than it looks like. For instance, if you work in base $7$, the number $7$ is written $10$, so you're looking for a number of the form $10****$ in base $7$ that is prime.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need only to use basic results about the distributions of primes to guarantee that, for example, a prime number must exist between 100 and 109, or 1000-1099, etc. You should be able to easily generalize this.

Comment: This simply restates the question and is insubstantial.