# Does the string of prime numbers contain all natural numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Does the string of prime numbers $$2357111317\ldots$$ contain every natural number as its sub-string?

Comment: It's unlikely to contain π as a substring, because π contains a decimal point and this string doesn't. Do you mean "every integer"?

Comment: No minus signs, @gnasher729. So has to refer to non-negative integers. :)

Comment: See [Copeland-Erdos constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copeland-Erdos_constant).

Comment: @Buddha, you didn't mention natural numbers, so change your question. And extending it to reals would be stupid because your string doesn't contain a decimal point or a minus character, so it doesn't contain the numbers 1.5 and -2, for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof that there are infinitely many prime numbers starting with a given digit string](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60825/proof-that-there-are-infinitely-many-prime-numbers-starting-with-a-given-digit-s)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

It follows from [Dirichlet's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions).

If $d$ is the number we want to find, define $s=10d+1$.  By definition, $\gcd(s,10)=1$ and $s$ contains the digits of $d$.

Dirichlet's Theorem's implies there's a prime of the form $p:=s+k \times 10^n$ where $10^n$ is chosen so that it has as many zeroes as digits of $s$.  The digits of $d$ appear in the digits of $p$, and thus in the given string of primes.

Comment: Very nice! This is actually exercise 4.16.b in Apostol's Introduction to Analytic Number Theory.

Comment: You should add that $k\in\mathbb N_{\ge 0}$.

Answer (score 35):

If you mean "every non-negative integer", then the answer is yes.

First, it contains the integer 0 as a substring because 101 is a prime.

Next, for every integer i > 0, there is a prime that starts with the integer i: Take the known results about gaps between prime numbers, for example that there is always a prime between $n^3$ and$(n+1)^3$ for large n. There is always a large n such that both $n^3$ and$(n+1)^3$ start with the digits of i, therefore the prime between $n^3$ and$(n+1)^3$ also starts with the digits of i.

(This is true because one of i, 10i and 100i is not the cube of an integer).

Comment: I love that you have two solutions here: you show that every $k$ is a prefix of a prime written in the decimal system, the other answer shows that every $k$ is a suffix of it :)

Comment: @tohecz Yes, it actually means there's no need to string the primes together, simply $2,3,5, \dots$ will contain all natural numbers somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

Let $n$ be a natural number, and let $\mathcal N(n)$ be the set of natural numbers not containing $n$ as a substring when written in base 10. It is well-known that $\sum_{k\in \mathcal N(n)}\frac{1}{k}$ converges.

Let $\mathcal P$ be the set of prime numbers. It is also well-known that $\sum_{p \in\mathcal P}\frac{1}{p}$ diverges.

Therefore it cannot be the case that $ \mathcal P\subseteq\mathcal N(n)$, and $n$ is therefore a substring of some prime (of infinitely many primes, in fact).

Answer (score 1):

It follows from the fact that the Copeland-Erdös constant is a normal number.

For any natural number $N$ with $k$ digits, $N$ appears in the Copeland-Erdos constant with a natural density of $10^{-k}$.