# Question about prime numbers starting with a given digits.

Tags: decimal-expansion

This question is about the previously answered question

[Proof that there are infinitely many prime numbers starting with a given digit string](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60825/proof-that-there-are-infinitely-many-prime-numbers-starting-with-a-given-digit-s?newreg=060c867eb1d24449982f930c7ec35899)

What I dont understand about the question is how the number
of beginning digits is related to the value n (referring to the answer by A. Nicholas). n will determine the length of the primes that starts with 
324 (in hexadecimal). Lets refer to the length of the beginning digits as L.
So for the case 324 then L=3.
So my question is what is the formula that
gives the bounds of n (or exact value of n) given L?

Comment: does there have to be one ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I would say that it is obvious that given there is a link between n and L. Because that previous question shows  n & L exist. So Im still waiting for someone to answer my question.