# Prove that there are infinitely many primes with $666$ in their decimal representation without Dirichlet's theorem.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

A satanic prime is a prime number with $666$ in the decimal representation.

The smallest satanic prime is $6661$.

Prove that there are infinitely many satanic primes.

---

I used Dirichlet's theorem for the progression $10000n+6661$ and it is done.

I'm interested in solutions without Dirichlet's theorem.

Comment: Dirichlet is a big hammer, but sometimes you need a big hammer :)

Comment: I suspect that, in a reasonable sense, *almost all* primes are satanic

Comment: I'd like to throw out here a (I think much harder) question: Are there infinitely many non-satanic primes?

Comment: @Nate Yes. Any prime with no 6 cannot be satanic. Maynard proved in 2016 that there are infinitely many primes with no 6 in their decimal expansions.

Comment: Is this true in general for any natural number?

Comment: @jdods Yes. For any natural number there are infinitely many primes containing, and infinitely many primes not containing, that number's decimal representation.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Let $x=666\cdot10^n$; it has $n+3$ digits. Consider the interval $(x,(1+1/666)x)=(666\cdot10^n,667\cdot10^n)$. Then the prime number theorem says that there is at least one prime in this interval for sufficiently large $x$; such a prime must begin with 666 and is thus satanic.

Concretely, use [Schoenfeld's 1976 result](https://doi.org/10.2307%2F2005976) that says for every $x\ge2010760$ there is a prime in $(x,(1+1/16597)x)$; we extend this interval to the $1+1/666$ interval above. So there is at least one satanic prime with $n$ digits for $n\ge7$, and the result is proved.

Comment: Thanks! If I understand correctly, your argument can prove that for any fixed digits there is a prime with these digits at the beginning, am I right?

Comment: @tong_nor Yes. For any $\epsilon>0$ and sufficiently large $x$ the prime number theorem guarantees at least one prime in $(x,(1+\epsilon)x)$.

Comment: I suspect Schoenfeld's result is a bigger hammer than Dirichlet, in a way.

Comment: @wythagoras These are Bertrand's postulate-type arguments. I happened to think of them first because I used them in my 14/21 interesting numbers answer...

Answer (score 108):

Consider the set $S$ of all numbers without 666 in their base 10 expression.  Here's a fun fact: the sum $\sum_{s\in S} \frac{1}{s}$ converges.  It's actually pretty easy to prove, so I'll leave it as an exercise (or google "Kempner series").

On the other hand, a famous result of Euler says the sum of the reciprocals of the prime numbers diverges.

Comment: Most Elementary answer yet. Also consider numbers to base 1000 with the omitted digit being 666.

Comment: "Perfection is achieved, not when there is nothing more to add, but when there is nothing left to take away." —Antoine de Saint-Exupéry

Comment: Current Wikipedia articles with details: [Kempner series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kempner_series) and [divergence of the sum of the reciprocals of the primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes)