# Show that there always exist prime $q$ such that $T_b(q)>T_b(p)$ for any prime $p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $n$ be a positive integer with some base $b$. Then $n$ can be represent as

$$n=( n_1 ... n_{l-1} n_l)_b$$

Let $T$ be the function defined as

$$T_b(n)= \sum_{i=1}^{l}n_i$$

**Example**

Let $n= (3596)_{10} = 3596$

So $$T_{10}(3596) = 3+5+9+6=23$$

> **Question**
>
> > Let base $b$ is given
> >
> > Show that for any prime $p$  there exist prime $q$ such that
> >
> > $$T_b(q)>T_b(p)$$

**Example**

Let base $b = 2$ and $p=17=(10001)_2$ then $T_2(17)=2$

So we can choose any prime $q\in \{7,11,13,19,...\}$ for $T_b(q)>T_b(p)$.

Comment: Dear Pruthviraj,
first note that your sum telescopes to $n_l-n_0$. Thus choosing say 19 ($T_10=8), you can't reach a higher number than 8(Contradicting the greater than). Besides, could you clarify your use of leading zeroes. I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: @IMOPUTFIE Okay thanks, you are right, I change $n_0\ne 0$

Comment: But when $n_0$ cannot be $0$, then as already stated 8 is the maximum for $T_10$, hence there doesn't exist $q$ such that: $T(q)>T(p)$

Comment: @IMOPUTFIE Okay if change $T_b(q)\geq T_b(p)$ then is it satisfied for problem?

Comment: Note that $q<p$. Thus choosing $p=2$, it is not correct.

Comment: I suspect that "for every base..." is meant to be a part of the premise. Currently, the claim can be interpreted as "$\forall p\ \exists q\ \forall b\ \ldots$" which is clearly false.

Comment: ... and the "$\forall p\ \forall b\ \exists q\ \ldots$" case is an easy consequence of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions).

Comment: @metamorphy Actually I'm not understand your conclusion, let suppose b=2 then what's wrong going in this problem, please explain

Comment: I mean, *currently* your claim *can be understood* as "for every prime $p$ there exists a prime $q>p$ such that *for every base* $b$ we have $T_b(q)>T_b(p)$", which is false (we can simply take $b=q$, when $T_q(q)=1$).

Comment: @metamorphy Now I fixed my statement please check.

Comment: The answer is yes, because ... see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60825/proof-that-there-are-infinitely-many-prime-numbers-starting-with-a-given-digit-s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the comment I posted yesterday, we can take the prime $p$ and convert it to base $b$, $(p)_{10}=(n_1n_2...n_{t_p})_b$. Then, there exists a prime $q$ which starts with the sequence of digits $n_1,n_2,...,n_{t_p}$, i.e. $(q)_{10}=(n_1n_2...n_{t_p}...n_{t_q})_b$ and $n_{t_q}\ne0$ (otherwise $b\mid q$, but $q$ is prime). Then
$$T_b(q)=n_1+n_2+...+n_{t_p}+...+n_{t_q}>n_1+n_2+...+n_{t_p}=T_b(p)$$

This is a direct result of [the fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60825/proof-that-there-are-infinitely-many-prime-numbers-starting-with-a-given-digit-s) that for any sequence of digits in base $b$, there is a prime number starting with that sequence, in that base.